# Sent an email via GMail and received a strange warning message

Tags: email, gmail

I have sent a mail from my GMail account and after a day have received following response.

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect
```

Can anyone explain why I received this?

Comment: Strange message? That looks quite regular to me, as well as very self explaining. "**The recipient server** did not accept our requests to connect"...

Answer (score 5):

It means that the server (the portion after the @ sign) may not be accepting e-mails, or might be malfunctioning.

Double check that the e-mail address is spelled correctly. It's not a problem with gmail, but the server  on the receiving end.